# How is the subspace of $L^2$ consisting of all compactly supported discontinuous functions related to $L^2/\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega$ be an open and bounded domain with a smooth boundary, and let a quotient space be defined as:
$$L^2/\mathbb{R} = \{q\in L^2(\Omega)\, \big |\, \int_\Omega q = 0\}.$$
Now let:
$$L^2_{00} = \{q \in L^2(\Omega)\, \big |\, q(x) = 0,\, \forall x\in\partial\Omega\}.$$

For each $q \in L^2_{00}$ I can find a $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that:
$$q+c \in L^2/\mathbb{R}.$$

Question. Based on the above, how is $L^2_{00}$ related to $L^2/\mathbb{R}$? Is it a closed subset?

Comment: Your definition of $L_{00}^{2}$ does not make sense.

Comment: As an explanation of @geetha290krm 's comment, $q$ is not defined on $\partial \Omega$. Also, $q$ is an equivalence class of functions, so you can't talk about its value on a point.

Comment: Let $f(x) = 1$ for $x\in(-1 + \varepsilon, 1-\varepsilon)$, $\varepsilon\in(0,1)$, and $f(x)=0$ for $x=\{-1,1\}$. Questions: Isn't such $f \in L^2$? And isn't such $f \in L^2_{00}$ as I defined it?